# How to customize ConvertUtilsBean.convert

Tags: java, javabeans

I am using `BeanUtils.describe` to get values from class contains JAXElement. How I can register custom converter for this class ?

In comment there is written it can be customized:

```
The registered {@link Converter} for the
     * <code>java.lang.String</code> class will be used, which allows
     * applications to customize Object->String conversions (the default
     * implementation simply uses toString()).
public String convert(Object value) {
```

but in code I just see it looks just for String converter:

```
        final Converter converter = lookup(String.class);
```

PS:

I tried:

```
   ConvertUtils.register(new Converter() {

        @Override
        public <T> T convert(Class<T> type, Object value) {
// TODO
            return null;

        }
    }, JAXBElement.class);
```

but with no success because as I said it looks just for String converters

Answer (score 0):

This function returns String, so it is looking for a converter that is converting given object to String too, as otherwise how it would be able to return it?
I think you misunderstood how it works, like javadoc is suggesting

> The registered `Converter` for the `java.lang.String` class will be used.

you just need to register your converter for String so you can convert that custom object to String. As `describe` method also need to return this data as String.